# Brainstorming a WCF/IIS Service Intermediary

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I have built a Windows forms application in C# using WCF for client -> server communication.  I have recently begun toying with Silverlight and built a web front end for the application which still uses the same WCF service for web client to server application.  What I'd like to do is have my WCF behind a firewall on a different machine and then build an "intermediary" WCF service which would live in a DMZ between IIS hosting my Silverlight client and the WCF box.

Essentially I want to seperate the WCF service which runs my windows forms application from also acting as a webserver.  Does it make sense to build this intermediary app to increase security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see how that would increase security other than forcing connections to the WCF service to go through the DMZ ... but a straight forward http proxy server would do the trick.

The intermediary becomes more useful when you have a whole bunch of services and you want to centralize things like aunthentication, message logging in a single location or if you want to do some fancy (or not so fancy) message routing such as load balancing between a few services.